# Using an ssd across computers

Tags: boot, ssd, desktop-computer, usb-3, portable

So I'm not sure what to call what I want to do or how stupid it might seem but I am wondering if it is possible to use one SSD across two different computers. For example, I have an external SSD that connects via USB 3.0. I want to be able to run Linux on it on my desktop. But then I want to be able to unplug it and plug it into a laptop so that I have the same OS and the same files and everything, just different hardware. I would do this so that I could use it on my desktop for gaming, take advantages of its high specs but then be able to take it with me via a laptop and be able to have all my files and everything right there. I guess the real question I'm asking is is this possible and if so is it reasonable?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible, but each time you plug it in and boot from a different machine with different motherboards/processors/gpu... it may have to reconfigure its hardware drivers.  Really depends on how different each machine is.  You may want to think about running a VM and virtualizing the drive so that all the hardware gets filtered through the VM.

Comment: Once I run it in both of them wouldn't all the drivers be installed? The drivers don't get overwritten do they? And can you explain the VM to me, I'm assuming that stands for virtual machine? Thanks for your answer btw!